# If form ==form1 and form2

Tags: forms

How can I make a hook form alter work on 2 forms?

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
if ( $form_id == 'node_page_form && node_page_edit_form'){
```

Comment: This is a plain PHP question: How do I execute some code when a string has one of two values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `||`:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_page_form' || $form_id == 'node_page_edit_form') {
    ...
  }
}
```